# Replicate POSTMAN GET request in C#/VB.net with Authorization

Tags: c#, vb.net, httpclient, request-headers

I've been here for 2 days now driving me nuts.

All I want to do it call a webservice at:

https://use-land-property-data.service.gov.uk/api/v1/datasets

Which returns some JSON object.

It requires the "Authorization" header to be set with an API Key that I have.

I've tried it in POSTMAN and it works.

[image]

However trying to get a Webclient or Httpclient version working is currently beyond me.  I've tried countless examples here on SO.   None return the same responses as POSTMAN.  All return "Request Rejected"

e.g.

```
 Using client = New HttpClient()

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "MYKEY")
            Dim response = Await client.GetStringAsync("https://use-land-property-data.service.gov.uk/api/v1/datasets")
           
            Return response
        End Using
```

what is the equivalent in `httpclient` to replicate the postman `Authorization` header?

Comment: Why are you using `WebClient` in 2021?

Comment: Also, why are you using VB.NET?

Comment: Your code looks fine as-is, so _something else_ (i.e. code that you haven't posted) is missing from your post.

Comment: I tried to access the Land Use Registry's web-service myself just now and I'm running into the same issues. Apparently the web-service is in beta and I've encountered a few bugs already (e.g. it ignoring the `Accept` header and always returns `text/html` responses). I suggest you contact them directly and ask them to fix things.

Comment: HttpClient sends a few more optional headers, you can try disable them like `Expect 100-continue` etc. I tried your request, but i don't get an API key without a credit card...
If you have an API key for me i can try help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Key")
```